# Running truffle migrate just opens my truffle.js file and does nothing

Tags: truffle

I am following this tutorial: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains.

I am trying to run truffle migrate on my project but it just opens my file in VSCode and nothing seems to happen. Any ideas what this problem is?

Comment: Are you using Windows? In such case I think it is because windows is trying to execute truffle.js, and it will open in visual studio code. If you are on Windows 10 I'll suggest to use the 'Bash on Ubuntu on Windows' instead. For other version use a virtual machine. Or if you know how to do it, use the full path to `truffle.cmd`.

Comment: @Ismael yes I am on Windows 10. Thank you for this tip, I will try this soon

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you are using windows it is because Windows is trying to execute the truffle.js file in your directory, and not the truffle command in your path. And since Visual Studio Code is associated with .js extension it will open it.

You can try with `truffle.cmd`. Or use the full path to `truffle.cmd`.

Also if you are on Windows 10 you can try 'Bash on Ubuntu on Windows' instead. For other versions you can use Ubuntu in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 8):

Windows CMD automatically appends some 'know extensions' to files when trying to run them. In this case it's changing your `truffle` command to `truffle.js` (instead of `...\node\bin\truffle.cmd`) because a `Truffle.js` file exists and `.js` is a 'known extension'.

CMD's 'know extensions' are stored in the PATHEXT environment variable, which in my machine contains: `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`

So, in my case, I just removed JS extension in the current console.

```
set PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

Or, I remove it system wide.

```
setx PATHEXT .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

(Please note `setx` does not update already opened consoles until you restart them.)

Comment: This worked for myself followed by a restart.

Comment: This worked after I reopened the console -- no restart required. The best answer IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Just use **Windows PowerShell** instead of **Command Prompt**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rename truffle.js to something else (truffle-bat.js) .
And here are the answers form truffleframework.com
1. Call the executable file explicitly using its .cmd extension (truffle.cmd compile)
2. Edit the system PATHEXT environment variable and remove .JS; from the list of executable extensions
3. Rename truffle.js to something else (truffle-config.js)
4. Use Windows PowerShell or Git BASH, as these shells do not have this conflict.
I chose the 3rd answers and solved my problem successfully.